# It was a place of palms and sand and cuffs - is "cuffs" a typo?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, literature

I am translating a story by Clark Ashton Smith, which contains the following part:

> It was a place of palms and sand and **cuffs**, with a small harbor
> sheltered by the curving outstretched arms of rugged reefs, on which
> the dark ocean climbed and gnashed its fangs of white foam without
> troubling the tranquil waters beyond.

I searched in several dictionaries but either I overlooked some entries or this is just wrong, by which I mean it could be OCR scanning error.
Or what "cuffs" could mean in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Books has scans of [The Collected Fantasies of Clark Ashton Smith: A Vintage From Atlantis](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yj1tDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT220&lpg=PT220&dq=%22It%20was%20a%20place%20of%20palms%20and%20sand%20and%22&source=bl&ots=kOEfaJwfQe&sig=ACfU3U27WjqVc8WBKyzUgHL8tiGVTIxApA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVjI2et4brAhU7knIEHft4Br4Q6AEwBXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22It%20was%20a%20place%20of%20palms%20and%20sand%20and%22&f=false) and [Pirate Ghosts of the American Coast: Stories of Hauntings at Sea](https://books.google.com/books?id=vuhZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22It%20was%20a%20place%20of%20palms%20and%20sand%20and%22&dq=%22It%20was%20a%20place%20of%20palms%20and%20sand%20and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtzaH2t4brAhV-g3IEHc5qC6YQ6AEINjAC), which have the word as “cliffs”.

[A Vintage from Atlantis](https://books.google.com/books?id=PYaRv1ro_DMC&pg=PP3&dq=%22It%20was%20a%20place%20of%20palms%20and%20sand%20and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtzaH2t4brAhV-g3IEHc5qC6YQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22It%20was%20a%20place%20of%20palms%20and%20sand%20and%22&f=false), on the other hand, has the word “cuffs” here.

It looks to me like it’s just a typo that appeared in some version(s) of the story. “Cuffs” doesn’t really even make sense as a metaphor, in my opinion.

Comment: If I may have one more question - a few sentences away, there is a phrase "and we were bending knee-deep in the tepid, lazy water". I cannot find any suitable meaning of "bend" in this context, but following your links this seems to be correct.

Comment: Could be an OCR error. These are common in online versions of printed books.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Are you referring to the word "bend" in my previous comment?

Comment: I was referring to the cuffs - cliffs error.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Right, thanks. And for the other problem, would you know, please? My first comment to this answer.

Comment: 'Bend' has its normal dictionary meaning.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well but it does not make much sense (to me). In that context, they are carrying barrels from the shore to their boats. So I would assume they walk in the water (fording?), but all the meanings of "bend" seem to express the act of bending (over). Why would you bend in the water, if you are not picking something up?

Comment: Barrels are often heavy. See answer below, with illustration.

Comment: Note: you ford a river or stream, not the sea. Walking in water is called 'wading'.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would you bend in the water, if you are not picking something up?

Observe the bending posture made necessary by a heavy load.

[image]

Comment: Note: this is a common way for people to hurt their backs.

Comment: Ah, right, now I got it, thanks a lot!